# Why the size of logo image change?

Tags: html, css, graphical-logo

I'm making my Blog.

And I made a theme.

But the image of the theme changes its size.

I want to keep it.

How can I do it?

it's url
http://www.rukkora.com

Please hover your cursor on logo image.

Sorry.I'm Japanese.

I can't type english well.

Comment: What do you want to do in this friend? you want to keep the size of the logo as is irrespective of hovering?

Answer (score 1):

In `style.css`, you have this:

```
#logo:hover
{
    background-size: 204px 70px;
    background: url(http://mdkx.net/img/logo-h.png);
}
```

Remove it and it should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

In your style.css Line 120 there is a :hover directive for the logo. remove it!